# Shader using DotProduct is creating stranger shadows

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, shadows, vector-mapping

I am attempting to create a stylized moss shader. My strategy is to use a dotproduct as shown below to drive an alpha mask.
[image]

In this example the mask material is applied to a sphere which is slightly offset from a blue spere. This is the result in cycles:
[image]

The shadow on the right side of the sphere is unexpected. I thought that I'd get a result like this:
[image]

How do I eliminate this shadow bug? (The shadow does not appear in Eevee)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the idea of the shader? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I see your clamping your values at the map range node but does clamping at the greater than do anything? I don't see why it would but it looks like a clamping issue. If that doesn't work try using the mask as the factor between mixing a Transparent BSDF and a Principled BSDF rather than plugging it straight into the alpha of the Principled.

Comment: This is just a guess, but by mapping the -1 to 1 values to 0 to 1, the negative normals get positive values as well and somehow they are now transparent from the outside, but not from the inside and that's why they are throwing shadows (completely technically uneducated guess). If you instead use _Generated_ or _Object_ coordinates and plug them into the _Normal_ node, this doesn't happen (and in this case you maybe don't need the _Map Range_ node).